# "Initial Menu Level" config in Block Layout not working

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

Using Drupal 8...

**Goal**

There are 2 regions in the header. The top region holds the **Level 1** menu links while the bottom region holds the **Level 2** menu links (or child links of the top regions).

[image: Menu structure]

What I want is for the **Who am I?** and **About** to only show on the top region. That's easy, **initial menu level is 1** and **max num of menu levels to display is 1**. That works great.

**Problem**

Problem comes along when I add the same menu to the bottom region and choose the following set up:

[image: the set up]

I thought that with these when a user clicks **About** on the top region, then the **child links** ("Just more links") of that menu link would be displayed on the bottom region. But nothing happens. It only works with the **Who am I?** link.

The only difference is that **Who am I?** points to **/node/2** while **About** points to the homepage with an added **?parameter=value**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

- The link for the menu item should be `<front>?parameter=value`
- The position and weight in the menu tree at `admin/structure/menu/manage/MENU_NAME`
- [This patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2811337) may be related